# 2 arquivos properties no Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Estou desenvolvendo uma API com Spring Boot, e tenho 2 arquivos properties para os ambientes de desenvolvimento e produção, Como faço para setar o arquivo properties de determinado ambiente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Adicione os *profiles* de **dev** e **prod** no seu arquivo **pom.xml**

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <spring.profile>dev</spring.profile>
        </properties>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <spring.profile>prod</spring.profile>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

**2.** Adicione a seguinte linha no seu arquivo **application.properties**:

```
spring.profiles.active=@spring.profile@
```

**3.** Crie dois arquivos que representem as suas configurações de **dev** e **prod**

```
application-dev.properties
application-prod.properties
```

**4.** Executar o projeto de acordo com o *profile*

**dev:** `mvn clean compile spring-boot:run`

**prod:** `mvn clean compile spring-boot:run -Pprod`

No meu GitHub tem um projeto com esta configuraçao. Links:

[pom.xml](https://github.com/WellingtonCosta/my-movies/blob/master/my-movies-api/pom.xml)

[application.properties](https://github.com/WellingtonCosta/my-movies/blob/master/my-movies-api/src/main/resources/application.properties)

[application-dev.properties](https://github.com/WellingtonCosta/my-movies/blob/master/my-movies-api/src/main/resources/application-dev.properties)

[application-prod.properties](https://github.com/WellingtonCosta/my-movies/blob/master/my-movies-api/src/main/resources/application-prod.properties)

Comment: obrigado, fiz igual aoqseu exemplo, porem ao fazer o deploy com o comand abaixo " mvn clean spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=prod ", ele pega o profile de desenvolvimento.

2017-10-10 14:39:00.464  INFO 5470 --- [  restartedMain] c.ernetwork.api.ApiErnetworkApplication  : The following profiles are active: dev

Sera que esqueci de algum detalhe?

Comment: Deu certo, rodei esse comando "mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.profiles=prod". Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: @wanderwang, que bom que deu certo! Há um tempo atrás passei por este mesmo problema. hehe